# jQuery: Hide/Show table rows based on clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got two tables side by side on a page. The left table contains buttons with company names, and the right table should contain employees connected to specific companies.

When you load the page there shouldn't be any employees. If the user clicks on one of the buttons, the table rows with the employees connected to this company should show up. If I click on the same button again or another button, the employee rows should hide (with the new ones popping up).

The buttons have a class with the company id (1, 2, 3..), and the rows have a class with an id like trclass1, trclass2, .. .

I tried using this function:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".clickbtn").click(function(event)
        {
            $('[id=trclass'+event.target.id+']').toggle();
        });
    });
```

clickbtn is the name of the button, trclass the class of the table rows.

```
<button id='1' class='clickbtn' />
<button id='2' class='clickbtn' />
.
.

<tr id='trclass1' hidden> ...
<tr id='trclass2' hidden> ...
.
.
```

It works *sometimes*. There seems no pattern if it works or doesnt work.

My problems are, except not knowing anything about jQuery, how to pass the argument properly to the function and making it work everytime. The jQuery code above was from another question which had quite the same problem, but was somehow different from mine. Last but not least, there isn't a constant number of how many companies or employees are there to show, the data is fetched from a database.

Comment: Perhaps this: `$('.clickbtn').click(function() { var btnID = $(this).attr("id"); $("#trclass"+btnID).toggle(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importance here is understanding the difference between jQuery's `$(this)` and plain old javascript `event.target`.

Consider [**this example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ndzjj2ud/).

The big blue box is our button, and it includes all the red boxes inside it. Notice, as you hover your mouse over them: `$(this)` always refers to the element in which the event is tied to. Because our event is tied to the **button** click, `$(this)` always refers to the **button**.

`event.target` on the other hand is almost *too-specific* in many cases. As you hover over the red boxes, you'll notice that `event.target` refers to *the exact element being hovered*. By doing `event.target.id`, you'll be getting the divs' ID's instead of the button's.

---

For this reason, I really think your solution is quite simple: Use jQuery's `$(this)` instead of `event.target`.

```
$('.clickbtn').click(function() { 
    var btnID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#trclass"+btnID).toggle();
});
```

---

If you want *only* the clicked button's row to be shown, then you can hide all of the others using `.hide()`. If you give your table an ID, you can select all the rows by doing `$("#my-table-id tr")`, however in your case you'll need to use a "starts with" selector `[id^=trclass]`. If this is the only table on the page, consider just using `$("tr")`, which selects every table row on the page.

```
$('.clickbtn').click(function() { 
    var btnID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("[id^=trclass]").not(this).hide();
    $("#trclass"+btnID).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is want it was intended to do. To hide the rows without the matching id, I changed the code to `$("[id^=trclass]").hide(); $("[id=trclass"+btnID).show();`. It works, but is this the only way to hide all the other rows? Just curious.

Comment: It's important to note the selectors in jQuery: For example, `$("#my-id")` selects an element `id="my-id"`, `$(".my-class")` selects an element `class="my-class"`, and finally `$("button")` selects an element `<button>`. I'll modify my answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds to be due to the elements being dynamically created. In order to get around this, you need to attach the click handler to an element that is always present on the page, which in turn **delegates the click event**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".clickbtn", function(event) {
    $('[id=trclass'+event.target.id+']').toggle();
  });
});
```

In the above sample, the click handler is attached to `document`, which fires whenever `.clickbtn` is clicked. This should cause the clicks to work every time.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'd venture to guess that if OP doesn't know jQuery, the elements "fetched from the database" are not dynamically created, but rather on pageload. Second, `event.target.id` will not always target the proper element if in fact there are multiple within the handler - it seems weird to me to use `event.target.id` when the intent is to grab the ID of the DOM element that fired the event. And thirdly, @RobertFrenette, event listeners cost you efficiency. Why have one listener for every single event as opposed to one single listener that handles them all?

Comment: It seems still to be random with your solution. The solution provided by @Santi above works as intended.

Comment: Ahh, I guess that the elements are not dynamically created then. I concede to @Santi; he appears to have found the valid solution :)